# how to select value from popup dropdown from below html

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have popup alert with dropdown values present in the popup. The values will be based previous selection list. Can anyone please help me with python selenium module to select value from this drop down.

```
<div class="none">
    <div id="selectfavcolor">
        <h3 class="popupTitle">Select your favourite color</h3>

        <div class="clearFix pdLR15">
            <!--newSelectBox start-->
            <div class="newSelectBox">
                <div class="dd-select-main clearFix">
                    <div id="myDropdown"></div>
                    <label id='SlctColorError' class='dispNone SlctErrors error'></label>
                </div>

                <div class="pdTB15 alRgt">
                    <a href="javascript:;" id="savecolor" class="darkYellowBtn">Save</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--newSelectBox end-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried like this . but it doesn't work.

```
select_make = driver.find_element_by_id('myDropdown')
for option in select_make.find_elements_by_tag_name('SlctColorError'):
    if option.text == 'Blue':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

Comment: I can see `Blue` in the html code. If it's not there, you can not click it.

Comment: Yes, it is not present in the code at first. It is getting updated dynamically from previous actions. When I selected 3 colors , a pop up is appearing to select the favorite color. In that popup I have a dropdown list of colors that I have selected .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming that the option `Blue` appears on the scereen when any other action is performed, 
a better way would be to wait until it appears on the screen and is clickable, and then click on it.
An example (code is in Java, because I don't know Phyton, but I belive you'll manage to convert it to Phyton):

```
final By blueOption = By.xpath( "//*[ text() = 'Blue' ]" ); 

/* wait max. 10 seconds then throw an exception if the option has't appeared */
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 

wait.until( ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable( blueOption )).click();
```